# How to select multiple check box with webdriver in java and verify?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Working on this page http://www.samsung.com/us/video/tvs/all-products
and wrote below piece of code to select multiple checkboxes.
But it is just selecting first checkbox and then giving me message that " element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up" 
Can anyone suggest, What I need to do for this?

```
enter code here

List <WebElement> checkBoxes =driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@name='filterOption']"));
   for(int i=0; i<checkBoxes.size(); i=i+2){
    checkBoxes.get(i).click();
    }
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    int checkedCount=0, uncheckedCount=0;
    for(int i=0; i<checkBoxes.size(); i++){
    System.out.println(i+" checkbox is selected "+checkBoxes.get(i).isSelected());
    if(checkBoxes.get(i).isSelected()){
                checkedCount++;
            }else{
                uncheckedCount++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("number of selected checkbox: "+checkedCount);
        System.out.println("number of unselected checkbox: "+uncheckedCount);
    }
```

Comment: Could you edit that into your question? It's impossible to read as a comment.

Comment: why do you have `i=i+2` in the first for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vivek's nailed the problem, however his code didn't work for me either. I made a few modifications to his solutions to make it work on chrome. First of all, I didn't use xpath and also I added webdriver wait so that we wait for the element before we click on it.

```
 WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
 driver.get("http://www.samsung.com/us/video/tvs/all-products");
 int length = driver.findElements(By.name("filterOption")).size();
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,300);
 for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    WebElement ele = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElements(By.name("filterOption")).get(i)));
      if (!ele.isSelected())
           ele.click();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Nilesh, It worked well with your code on FF and Chrome browser.

Answer (score 1):

Since on clicking an input tag your webpage is getting refreshed, so the error. As a workaround, you can try out with:

```
int length = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//fieldset/input")).size();
WebElement ele = null;
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//fieldset/input)[" + i + "]")); // searching for new element after every reload
    if (!ele.isSelected())
        ele.click();
}
```

Comment: Vivek, I tried with your method, but no success, Is there any other altervative way to do ?

Comment: Is it? strange... I tried this on the url u provided...it was working smooth...whats the issue you had?